# Can someone help me understand Retrofit2 POST requests?

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit2

I'm trying to build a login/registration system using retrofit2 in android studio and I cannot figure out for the life of me what I am doing wrong I've tried multiple test API's and they return the correct response.

To give you a breakdown My API Needs three things for login (That's the following): {"uid": "username", "pwd":"password", "auth_mode": "basic"}

Word of warning this is my first time using retro fit and even then my first time building an app any help would be appreciated.

userService.java -->

```
public interface UserService {


@POST("https://providencewebservices.co.uk/api-test/v1/login.php?method=json")
Call<LoginResponse> userLogin ();
```

login.java -->

```
public void login(){
    LoginRequest loginRequest = new LoginRequest();
    loginRequest.setEmail(email.getText().toString());
    loginRequest.setPassword(password.getText().toString());


    Call<LoginResponse> loginResponseCall = APiClient.getUserService().userLogin();
    loginResponseCall.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {

            if(response.isSuccessful()){
                Toast.makeText(login.this,"Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                LoginResponse loginResponse = response.body();

                new Handler ( Looper.getMainLooper () ).postDelayed( new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        startActivity(new Intent (login.this, UserDashboard.class));
                    }
                },700);

            }else{
                Toast.makeText(login.this,"Login Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(login.this,"Throwable "+t.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });


}
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe that you missed sending: `{"uid": "username", "pwd":"password", "auth_mode": "basic"}`  to the service.

```
@POST("https://providencewebservices.co.uk/api-test/v1/login.php?method=json")
Call<LoginResponse> userLogin (@Body LoginRequest data);
```

And `LoginRequest.java` is something like (assuming you are using gson)

```
class LoginRequest {
    private String uid;
    private String pwd;
    @SerializedName("auth_mode")
    private String authMode;
}
```